# Mobile redirection 'fullsite' cookie always redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am using this script to redirect mobile users to the mobile page and make them able to get back to the full site

```
(function(a,b) {

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        return; // skip redirect
    }
    if (location.search.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        document.cookie = 'fullsite=true; path=/;'
        return; // skip redirect
    } 
    if (mobile regexp) {
        window.location = b;
    }
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'desired.mobile.url')
```

The problem is that it redirects PC users too unless the url is pageurl.com/fullsite
What is wrong with the script?